# Youtube Data API V3 - No Video url

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data api version 3, to get the top youtube videos, i am calling the REST api like this:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&forMine=true&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&type=video&_h=6&

and get the data like this is json format:

```
"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
"etag": "adasdasdasdasdas",
"id": 
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "videoId": "123123asdsad12"
},
"snippet": 
{
  "publishedAt": "date",
  "channelId": "Gasdqqweqweqwr123123",
  "title": "my tutle",
  "description": "xyz",
  "thumbnails": 
  {
    "default": 
    {
      "url": "......jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
    },
    "medium": 
    {
      "url": "......jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
    },
    "high": 
    {
      "url": "......jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
    }
  },
  "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
}
```

but this data do not contain youtube video url, how can i obtain it from the api?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can have the video url like this :

You have the result :

```
     "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
"etag": "\"adasdasdasdasdas"",
"id": {
"kind": "youtube#video",
"videoId": "123123asdsad12"
},
...
```

Now you get the field `"videoId": "123123asdsad12"`

And you can acces to the video via the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**123123asdsad12**

And that's it !

Comment: Is there a way to get full link programmatically? we have the id that is OK, but what if the link format changes for example "id" instead of "v". Like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?id=123123asdsad12"

Comment: it's `v` ad it never change :)

Comment: Why is that the correct answer? That youtube link sends to the HTML youtube page. It would be better using the youtube embed link https://www.youtube.com/embed/{The id}

Answer (score 1):

on your query, the "part" property actually indicates what information you want for the call to return, the "snippet" valie will return a more detailed information for each result, if you want the "videoID" data do the following, on the "part" property add "id" value, like this: ...?part=snippet,id&...

that will get you the data that contains the videoID information.

regards.