# Getting the url of the youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to get the youtube video without the youtube player? The youtube player sdk - https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/
uses the existing youtube player, I need the url that it uses to play the video, so that I can use my custom video player. More of using youtube as a hosting service, where I can pull the videos from the server from which youtube player pulls it. Don't know if it is possible or legal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423808/youtube-data-api-v3-no-video-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746449/youtube-api-v3-search-for-videos-retrieve-title-and-url

Comment: @d.datul1990- no it is not, those answers seem to give the url to the youtube player playing the video, I need the stream url which that player internally uses